# wordpress how to call menu

Tags: php, wordpress, wp-nav-menu-item

I try to use `wp_nav_menu` in my website.
My menu structure following like

```
 Home
 About
 Insight 
   Test
   Test
 About2
   Test
   Test
```

When i call menu using 
like this

```
       <?php
            // Primary navigation menu.
            wp_nav_menu(
            'menu_class'     => 'main-nav navbar-nav ml-auto',
            'container' => false,
            'theme_location' => 'header-menu',
                //'items_wrap'      => '<ul>%3$s</ul>',
                'depth' => 4,
            //
             );

        ?>
```

All main and sub menu view home page how to stop this

Comment: what do you want to say here?

Comment: How did you register the nav menu? `register_nav_menu()`

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to call the array.

```
<?php
// Primary navigation menu.
wp_nav_menu( array(
    [
        'menu_class' => 'main-nav navbar-nav ml-auto',
        'container' => false,
        'theme_location' => 'header-menu',
        //'items_wrap'      => '<ul>%3$s</ul>',
        'depth' => 4,
        //
    ]
)  );
?>
```

Comment: My main wp_nav_menu is called header-menu
and that menu like this

Home
About
Insight 
  Test1
  Test1
About2
  Test
  Test

I want to call this menu in home page without showing sub items . That can i do using 
                        <?php   wp_nav_menu( array(
    'menu_class'     => 'main-nav navbar-nav ml-auto',
    'container' => false,
    'theme_location' => 'header-menu',
     'depth' => 1,
    ) );?>
But after when i go to the Insight page i want to show secondary main menu and secondary menu (only test1 and test2) How can i do this

Comment: I'm not sure how experienced you are with coding or PHP in general, so picking up some good basics might be a good idea before proceeding do some tutorials on the topic. That being said, if you want a secondary menu on the next page you need to call up a new array on that page.